# What are the risks of changing LAN network ID from 192.168.0.X to 100.100.0.X?

Tags: networking, lan, cisco-anyconnect

Roommate is using *Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client* VPN, and when connected to this network, he is unable to reach other local devices in our `192.168.0.X` local network. However, he was told if he changes the local network ID to `100.100.0.X`, he will be able to stay connected to the VPN and have connections between his local devices.

And that's right, it works for him. However, I don't understand why his VPN requires to change local network from `192.168.X.X` to `100.100.X.X` if the VPN itself has a `172.23.X.X` network ID (and 0xfffff000 netmask). Why would it be blocking or redirecting local traffic from `192.172.0.X` but not from `100.100.0.X` hosts if both address pools are outside from the Cisco VPN network.

This change makes me a bit uncomfortable because `100.100.0.X` is not a standard private network ID.

What issues could we face if we keep the `100.100.0.X` local networkID?

Comment: `100.100.0.0/24` is covered by the [Carrier-Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) reserved range (`100.64.0.0/10`)... i.e: this should be "_fairly harmless_", unless your ISP is using the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why would it be blocking or redirecting local traffic from 192.172.0.X but not from 100.100.0.X hosts if both address pools are outside from the Cisco VPN network

The Cisco AnyConnect VPN client has a feature where it deliberately **blocks all LAN access** while connected to the VPN. (Normally this can be disabled in the client's settings screen, unless the administrators have deployed a profile preventing this.)

"LAN" basically means the three RFC 1918 reserved ranges (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16). Your friend avoids the blocking simply by choosing a network address outside those ranges.

> This change makes me a bit uncomfortable because 100.100.0.X is not a standard private network ID.

Yes, but it *is* actually a private network address – just not one meant to be used on end-networks. Instead, the entire 100.64.0.0/10 prefix is meant to be used by ISPs, specifically [to avoid conflicts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_shared_address_space) with the "usual" RFC 1918 ranges.

(For a router it's necessary that all interfaces use non-conflicting address ranges. So when CGNAT is in use, there would be problems if the customer's own LAN addresses happen to conflict with the ISP-level internal addresses.)

> What issues could we face if we keep the 100.100.0.X local networkID?

If your ISP ends up deploying CGNAT and starts assigning you "WAN" IP addresses from this exact range, your router will no longer know which way to forward packets.

Other than that, it's not a very bad choice.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the detailed explanation. I quick Bing search didn't return anything about Comcast using CGNAT.